# tel: no longer working in wkwebview Cordova app Cordova iOS 5.1.1

Tags: html, cordova

`<a href="tel:" >` doesn't seem to be bringing up tel keyboard in latest Cordova with WKwebview being used. 
Does anyone have this experience? Ive searched but can't find decent current solution.

Comment: Ok had to Use a plugin instead to circumvent this issue.